# mongodb C# compare date without time

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

How to compare date without time in mongodb C# driver?

I try to use this code, bot it don't work.

```
MongoCursor<Log> query = _logCollection.FindAs<Log>(
                               Query.And(Query.EQ("Date.getDate()", date.Day),
                                         Query.EQ("Date.getMonth()", date.Month),
                                         Query.EQ("Date.getYear()", date.Year)));
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Query for range of dates, which include your date:

```
var beginDate = date.Date;          // e.g. 7/24/2013 00:00:00
var endDate = beginDate.AddDays(1); // e.g. 7/25/2013 00:00:00

var query = Query.And(Query<Log>.GTE(l => l.Date, beginDate), // including
                      Query<Log>.LT(l => l.Date, endDate)); // not including

var result = _logCollection.FindAs<Log>(query);
```

Same with LINQ (*MongoDB.Driver.Linq* namespace):

```
var result = from l in _logCollection.AsQueryable()
             where l.Date >= beginDate && l.Date < endDate
             select l;
```